# Deny,Allow on .htaccess isn't working

Tags: htaccess

i'm trying to deny all access to wp-login php and grant access to specified public addresses but it only block everyone whitout granting the specified addresses access

this the config used

```
<files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from MyPublicIP
</files>
```

Comment: Use lower case may help.

Comment: Already done .. not working

Comment: Do you have an appropriate 'AllowOverride' in your http server config. Both Apache and Nginx will ignore .htaccess if allow override isn't correct. Just a thought. Also, verify your IP address. I know my IP address is proxied therefore my actual address is different to what the server sees.

Comment: The fact that the deny directive works means that everything is configured right ?

Comment: @AbdelhakRahmouni You're right, I hadn't picked up on that detail. If the deny is working then your server is probably configured correctly. Sorry, that's about my limit of help on this.